# Compare two array of hashes with same keys

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have 2 arrays of hashes with same keys but different values.

```
A = [{:a=>1, :b=>4, :c=>2},{:a=>2, :b=>1, :c=>3}]
B = [{:a=>1, :b=>1, :c=>2},{:a=>1, :b=>3, :c=>3}]
```

I'm trying to compare 1st hash in A with 1st hash in B and so on using their keys and identify which key and which value is not matching if they do not match. please help.

```
    A.each_key do |key|
      if A[key] ==  B[key]
        puts "#{key} match"
      else
        puts "#{key} dont match"
```

Answer (score 6):

I am not certain which comparisons you want to make, so I will show ways of answering different questions. You want to make pairwise comparisons of two arrays of hashes, but that's really no more difficult than just comparing two hashes, as I will show later. For now, suppose you merely want to compare two hashes:

```
h1 = {:a=>1, :b=>4, :c=>2, :d=>3 }
h2 = {:a=>1, :b=>1, :c=>2, :e=>5 }
```

*What keys are in `h1` or `h2` (or both)?*

```
h1.keys | h2.keys
  #=> [:a, :b, :c, :d, :e]
```

See [Array#|](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-7C).

*What keys are in both hashes?*

```
h1.keys & h2.keys
  #=> [:a, :b, :c]
```

See [Array#&](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-26).

*What keys are in `h1` but not `h2`?*

```
h1.keys - h2.keys
  #=> [:d]
```

See [Array#-](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-2D).

*What keys are in `h2` but not `h1`?*

```
h2.keys - h1.keys #=> [:e]
```

*What keys are in one hash only?*

```
(h1.keys - h2.keys) | (h2.keys - h1.keys)
  #=> [:d, :e]
```

or

```
(h1.keys | h2.keys) - (h1.keys & h2.keys)
```

*What keys are in both hashes and have the same values in both hashes?*

```
(h1.keys & h2.keys).select { |k| h1[k] == h2[k] }
  #=> [:a, :c]
```

See [Array#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select).

*What keys are in both hashes and have different values in the two hashes?*

```
(h1.keys & h2.keys).reject { |k| h1[k] == h2[k] }
  #=> [:b]
```

Suppose now we had two arrays of hashes:

```
a1 = [{:a=>1, :b=>4, :c=>2, :d=>3 }, {:a=>2, :b=>1, :c=>3, :d=>4}]
a2 = [{:a=>1, :b=>1, :c=>2, :e=>5 }, {:a=>1, :b=>3, :c=>3, :e=> 6}]
```

and wished to compare the hashes pairwise. To do that first take the computation of interest above and wrap it in a method. For example:

```
def keys_in_both_with_different_values(h1, h2)
  (h1.keys & h2.keys).reject { |k| h1[k] == h2[k] }
end
```

Then write:

```
a1.zip(a2).map { |h1,h2| keys_in_both_with_different_values(h1, h2) }
  #=> [[:b], [:a, :b]]
```

See [Enumerable#zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're comparing elements of arrays...

```
A.each_with_index do |hasha, index|
  hashb = B[index]
  hasha.each_key do |key|
    if hasha[key] == hashb[key]
      puts "in array #{index} the key #{key} matches"
    else
      puts "in array #{index} the key #{key} doesn't match"
    end
  end
end
```

edit - added a missing `end`!

Comment: Thank you, Steve. that was helpful !

Comment: Great!  If you like the answer, please don't hesitate to accept it (there's an option next to the answer to do that)

Answer (score 0):

When you are dealing with an array, you should reference an element with open-close bracket '[]' as in

```
A[index at which lies the element you are looking for]
```

If you want to access an element in a hash, you want to use open-close bracket with the corresponding key in it, as in

```
A[:a]
```

(referencing the value that corresponds to the key ':a', which is of a type symbol.)

In this case, the arrays in question are such that hashes are nested within an array. So for example, the expression B[0][:c] will give 2.

To compare the 1st hash in A with the 1st hash in B, the 2nd hash in A with the second hash in B and so forth, you can use each_with_index method on an Array object ,like so;

```
A = [{:a=>1, :b=>4, :c=>2},{:a=>2, :b=>1, :c=>3}]
B = [{:a=>1, :b=>1, :c=>2},{:a=>1, :b=>3, :c=>3}]
sym = [:a, :b, :c]

A.each_with_index do |hash_a, idx_a|
  sym.each do |sym|
    if A[idx_a][sym] == B[idx_a][sym]
      puts "Match found! (key -- :#{sym}, value -- #{A[idx_a][sym]})"
    else
      puts "No match here."
    end 
  end
end
```

which is checking the values based on the keys, which are symbols, in the following order; :a -> :b -> :c -> :a -> :b -> :c 
This will print out;

```
Match found! (key -- :a, value -- 1)
No match here.
Match found! (key -- :c, value -- 2)
No match here.
No match here.
Match found! (key -- :c, value -- 3)
```

The method each_with_index may look a little bit cryptic if you are not familiar with it. 
If you are uncomfortable with it you might want to check;
http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_index

Last but not least, don't forget to add 'end'(s) at the end of a block (i.e. the code between do/end) and if statement in your code.

I hope it helps.